# How can I handle a really slow DOM operation so it doesn't block?

Tags: javascript, paperjs

I have to execute a really slow (20 secs+) operation that involves the DOM. Specifically, a `paper.js` SVG export:

```
project.exportSVG({ asString: true, matchShapes: true, precision: 2 })
```

which repeatedly calls `document.createElementNS` (see [here](https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/blob/095671073b9cfed2221b48aea54776ca6f2aed70/src/svg/SvgElement.js#L34)).

Since DOM operations aren't possible in workers, I can't use them to run this.

I tried using promises like this:

```
(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   console.time('export')
   var p = project;
    resolve(p.exportSVG({ asString: true, matchShapes: true, precision: 2 }));
   console.timeEnd('export')
})).then(svg => { console.log(svg) })
```

but it still blocks for ages.

Is there any other way I can run this without blocking for a long time?

Comment: Use a Promise respective await/async.

Comment: @MarkusZeller - tried that, still blocks (document.createElementNS gets called thousands of times)

Comment: onload event try to simply run a timeout to start your script, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26615966/how-to-make-non-blocking-javascript-code

Comment: One possible way would be to run your Paper.js operation on the server to decouple it from your frontend Javascript code.

Comment: Probably you can tweak Paper.js code a little bit, maybe wrapping calls to ```document.createElementNS``` in a ```setTimeout(call, 0)``` will allow to unblock event queue a little bit. But it needs to be investigated. @simone can you setup a JSFiddle so we'll be able to reproduce those heavy DOM operations?

Comment: You can't use a promise to make synchronous code into asynchronous code. You can use some promise techniques to change the scheduling of when code runs, but synchronous code in Javascript is still synchronous and blocking code in Javascript no matter when it runs.

Promises are purely a notification system for notifying you when some other operation has told a promise that it is now resolved or rejected. They don't magically convert synchronous code into asynchronous code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50825071/why-is-my-chained-promise-blocking

Comment: So use asynchronous programming if you wait for some resource, or external input, a database result to not block the execution flow while waiting for the data to arrive etc.. I suggest as the other guy said to use a server side implementation.

Comment: You can try this with NodeJS. https://github.com/wilk/microjob